# Can't subscribe to results of combineLatest

Tags: firebase, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

My app broke when I updated to RxJS 6. I got most of it working but this one method has me stumped.

Previously we had an array of observables being flatMapped and then used combineLatest like this:

```
const newObservable = myArrayOfObservables
   .flatMap(observables => {
       return Observable.combineLatest(observables);
   });
```

And I could subscribe to the newObservable and get an array of the latest outputs from all the others.

Now I'm trying to do something like this:

```
const mergedList$ = chatList$.pipe(
  mergeMap(res => {
    return combineLatest(res);
  }));
```

This gives me one of those really long and convoluted

> Argument of type '(res: Observable<{ $key: string; }>[]) => OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, Observable<{ $key: string; }>]>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Observable<{ $key: string; }>[], index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
>     Type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, Observable<{ $key: string; }>]>' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
>       Type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, Observable<{ $key: string; }>]>' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{}>'.
>         Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type 'OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, Observable<{ $key: string; }>]>'.

which quite frankly my dyslexia prevents me from parsing.

If I just return res in the above, and then try

```
const mergeCombo = combineLatest(mergedList$);
```

now mergeCombo is not an observable. Instead it's a

> OperatorFunction<{}, [{}, Observable<{
>           $key: string;
>       }>]>

It could be worth noting that my original observables are being emitted by AngularFireObject.snapshotChanges()

Answer (score 13):

You don't show how you imported `combineLatest`.  It sort of looks like you are importing it as an operator, which has been deprecated.

Make sure you import it like so:

```
import {combineLatest} from "rxjs";
```

Then your original code should work just fine:

```
const mergedList$ = chatList$.pipe(
  mergeMap(res => combineLatest(res))
);
```